# Need a hint for the problem $x + 3^x < 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

$x + 3^x < 4$

It's clear from looking at it that the answer is x < 1, but I want to solve it algebraically and that's what i'm having trouble with. I've messed around with it for a while and i've gotten nowhere. Logarithms just take me in a circle--for instance:

$3^x < 4 - x$

$\ln(3^x) < \ln(4-x)$

$x\ln(3) < \ln(4-x)$

$x<\frac{\ln(4-x)}{\ln(3)}$

$x < \log_3(4-x)$

$ 3^x < 4 - x$

and boom I'm back where I started.

I'm wondering if someone can just point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Hardly any method for these kind of inequalities.. Plotting both sides should be fair enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to look at the equation $x+3^x=4$, argue that $1$ is a solution and that since $x\to x+3^x$ is increasing it can only have one solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean exactly by ‘algebraically’, but you may observe the function is increasing (sum of two increasing functions – no derivative required here). As $1+3^1=4$, this means $x+3^x<4$ if $x<1$, $x+3^x>4$ if $x>1$.

Comment: I meant manipulate it somehow to get x on one side as you can do with many other problems. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x)=x+3^x\\f'=1+3^x.\ln3 >0$$is increasing function.
so f(x)=4 has at least 1 root(solution)
now you can write inequality in this form 
$$x+3^x<4\\x+3^3<1+3^1 \to x<1$$[image]